# Return.portfolio error from PerformanceAnalytics package

Tags: time-series, portfolio-management, r, performanceanalytics

When using the PerformanceAnalytics package of R, I am getting an error from the Return.portfolio function whenever I ask it to rebalance_on any frequency.  If the rebalance parameter is removed, the function works fine.

Return.portfolio(portfolio.returns.daily, weights=risk.weights, rebalance_on="months")

Error in `[<-`(`*tmp*`, k, , value = c(0.734291071622665, 0.629392347105141,  : 
  subscript out of bounds

Comment: please provide reproducible data to help you. We just need the portion that will result in the error, You can dput() in r & paste it here

Answer (score 1):

Just ran into and solved this problem.

Convert the timeSeries object into an xts object then change the indexClass to "Date"

```
# returns is a timeSeries object
r <- as.xts(returns)
indexClass(r) <- "Date"
a <- Return.portfolio(r, rebalance_on="quarters", verbose=TRUE)
```

I'm not an R expert or anything so I don't know if changing the indexClass has any other ramifications, but this allows me Return.portfolio to work.